# How to read safari app settings

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

I am developing an web ios app where i am struck with pdf download . When i turn off "Block-ups" option in safari settings i am able to view the pdf using SFSafariViewController . But i need to know the status of "Block-ups" slider so that i can show the alert if it on "Please turn off that Block-ups options in settings" to view the pdf.

I tried this

```
UIApplication.shared.open(NSURL(string:"App-Prefs:root=SAFARI")! as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

But it is opening the settings page. If there is way to know the status like location manager that will help me.

Comment: Apple does not allow you to read those settings. There is not way to do this with the public API.

Comment: Any hacky approach?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, there might be some private API that can do it, but them you will be rejected because you can use private API's